# I making line chatbot and i have some problem about promise

Tags: node.js, promise

I making line chatbot using heroku and node.js and then when i verify webhook I got an error

[Here it's an error on line developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnYJA.png)

and when i run /webhook and error here

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()

and

> DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

here my code

```
    app.post('/webhook', line.middleware(config), (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200)
    Promise
    .all(req.body.events.map(handleEvent))
    .then((result) => res.json(result))
    .catch();
    throw new Error('Failed');
});
```

I think i make the wrong promise need help and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Express, try this:

```
app.post('/webhook', line.middleware(config), (req, res) => {
  Promise
    .all(req.body.events.map(handleEvent))
    .then(result => res.status(200).json(result))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).end('Failed'));
});
```

Alternatively, you could forward the error to the Express error handler using the `next` function:

```
app.post('/webhook', line.middleware(config), (req, res, next) => {
  Promise
    .all(req.body.events.map(handleEvent))
    .then(result => res.status(200).json(result))
    .catch(err => next(err));
});
```